# GPS location log

Tags: gps

I had GPS enabled on my phone one night and I'm trying to find a log on my phone of where I was and when. I didn't have WiFi or data on, so the `cache.wifi` and `cache.cell` files are incomplete. Google Location history turns up nothing either.

My phone runs Android 2.3. Are precise GPS data logged anywhere in the system (I didn't have any GPS logging apps installed at the time)?

Answer (score 2):

If your device is rooted, you might want to take a look at [Location Cache](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.rrelmy.android.locationcachemap) or (if your Android version is lower than 2.3.3) also [Android Location Cache Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bafflesoft.locationcache.viewer). Both apps give you insight into Google's location cache, the first even permits you to clean or disable it.

[image: Location Cache] [image: Location Cache menu]
<sup>Location Cache (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ch.rrelmy.android.locationcachemap))</sup>

Note that those apps stopped working with Android 2.3.3 (Cache Viewer) resp. Android 4.0 (Location Cache).

Comment: It looks like both these apps are just frontends for the `cache.wifi` and `cache.cell` files unfortunately. From what I can see android doesn't seem to log GPS activity unless you have an app that explicitly does this, unless it's hidden somewhere no-one knows about.

Comment: As far as I remember, at least *Location Cache* also shows GPS locations (I've used this app a while ago).